# How to get percentage data from a Pivot Table where filters are applied?

Tags: excel, pivot-table, filtering, percentage, dynamic-pivot

The screenshot below has data at left side.
[image]

I want to see the variation of percentage of fresh apples over the months.
That is, the percenatge of fresh apples for Jan is 25% (10 of 40) and so on.

But in the pivot table, after keeping the filter of "Fresh", I am only able to get the percentage of Grand Total. Percentage of Parent Row Total does not return any values.

The final result I want is shown below the pivot table. Please explain how this can be achieved.